# right continuity of the filtration generated by coordinate mappings

Tags: probability, continuity, stochastic-processes

Suppose $E$ is an interval in the real line. Let $(E^{\mathbb{R}_+}, \mathscr{F})$ be the canonical probability space. Suppose $\{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is the collection of coordinate mappings and let $\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$ be the filtration generated by $\{X_t\}$. Is $\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$ right continuous, i.e., is $$\mathscr{F}_t = \cap_{s > t} \mathscr{F}_s$$ true for all $t \geq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

No.  For a counter example, we have that $$A:=\left\{\lim_{\substack{t \downarrow 0 \\ t \in \mathbb{Q}}} X_t = 0\right\} \in \bigcap_{s > 0} \mathcal F_s$$ but $\mathcal F_0 = \sigma(X_0)$ so $A \not \in \mathcal F_0$.  I will show $$B:=\left\{\limsup_{\substack{t \downarrow 0 \\ t \in \mathbb{Q}}} X_t \le 0\right\} \in \bigcap_{s > 0} \mathcal F_s,$$ the arguments for $\liminf X_t \ge 0$ are similar.  We write \begin{align*}
\left\{\limsup_{\substack{t \downarrow 0 \\ t \in \mathbb{Q}}} X_t \le 0\right\} &= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{T \in \mathbb{Q}} \bigcap_{\substack{t \in \mathbb{Q} \\t < T}}\left\{X_t \le \frac 1n\right\}.
\end{align*}

Note that for any $s > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$\bigcup_{T \in \mathbb{Q}} \bigcap_{\substack{t \in \mathbb{Q} \\t < T}}\left\{X_t \le \frac 1n\right\} = \bigcup_{\substack{T \in \mathbb{Q} \\ T \le s}} \bigcap_{\substack{t \in \mathbb{Q} \\t < T}}\left\{X_t \le \frac 1n\right\},$$ so $B \in \mathcal F_s$ for all $s > 0$.  Therefore we conclude $B \in \bigcap_{s > 0} \mathcal F_s$.

For a more concrete example, we could consider a random variable $Y$ with $\mathbb{P}(Y = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Y = -1) = \frac 12$ and define $X_t := Yt$.  Then $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\bigcap_{s > 0} \mathcal F_s$ but not with respect to $\mathcal F_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Could you please elaborate more on the first example? Especially, why is $A$ in $\cap_{s > 0} \mathcal{F}_s$. The second example is easy to understand, and I know that the natural filtration of an arbitrary stochastic process usually does not process good properties. But my question is concerning the coordinate process on the standard probability space. Thanks!

Comment: I will elaborate on the first example.  I actually now realize I will need to slightly modify it, though, since we aren't assuming the processes are continuous.  I don't see what the probability space has to do with the example.  I think you can always take the probability space on which a stochastic process is defined to be the standard probability space.